# How to change acceleration of kart from ArcadeKart.cs in struct Stats in karting microgame

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a very new coder and I'm trying to make a powerup that increases the acceleration limit of the kart. But using `GetComponent<KartGame.KartSystems.ArcadeKart>` I'm not sure how to change Acceleration when it's inside a struct called "stats"

Comment: Could you share the code or link to whatever code you are using? .. what is `KartGame.KartSystems.ArcadeKart`?

Answer (score 0):

I havent seen this code, but when you type this (after the dot I mean)

```
GetComponent<KartGame.KartSystems.ArcadeKart>().
```

You will be shown a list of the variables and functions you have access from there, so hopefully you can see one that is speed in the list or something similar